# getting brands of products with discounts

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make search in brands where thy have discounted products.

## Discount Logic

Discount table will save `product_id`, and product has `brand_id`

## What I want

1. I need solution to get out brands of products that their id is saved in discount table and list them.
2. After that I want to select each of those brands and show result of
   products which has discount and has this brand id.

## Codes

here is how I get my discounted products:

```
$promotions = Discount::with('products')->Valid()->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(12);
```

This is my brands:

```
$brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')->get();
```

here is my full code:

```
        // Index `Promotion` page (where all results are mixed from all brands etc.)
            public function promotions() {
                $promotions = Discount::with('products')->Valid()->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(12); // get all discounted products
                $options = Option::all(); // for my sidebar only
                $brands = Brand::OfStatus('Active')->get(); // for my sidebar only



                $brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')->get();
//this has to be change to some query in order to only get brands of discounted products
//result of this i will use in drop-down select box.




                return view('front.promotions', compact('promotions', 'options', 'brandspromotion', 'brands'));
              }

    // this function will take care of chosen brand result
          public function brandspromotions($slug) {
            //
          }
```

any idea?

## UPDATE

I changed my query to something like code below:

```
$promotions2 = Discount::with('products')->Valid()->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
    foreach($promotions2 as $brandpro){
      $brand_id = $brandpro->products->brand_id;
    }
    $brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')
    ->where('id', '=', $brand_id)->get();
```

It is working but only gets `1` brand, something with my loop has to be wrong!

## Update 2

I tried to use `map` here is my code:

```
$promotions2 = Discount::with('products')->Valid()->get();
    $grouped = $promotions2->map(function ($item, $key) {
      return $item->products->brand_id;
    });
    $grouped->all();
    // dd($grouped);
    $brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')
    ->where('id', '=', $grouped)->get();
```

result is like:

```
Collection {#713 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
    3 => 1
  ]
}
```

I suppose to get `lenovo` (id:1) and `lg` (id:2) but i only get `lg`.

## UPDATE 3

```
$promotions2 = Discount::with('products')->Valid()->get();
$grouped = $promotions2->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item->products->brand_id => $item->products->brand_id];
});
dd($grouped);
$brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')
->where('id', '=', $grouped->all())->get();
```

Result:

```
Collection {#704 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    2 => Collection {#710 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => 2
        1 => 2
      ]
    }
    1 => Collection {#703 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => 1
        1 => 1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Issue:

> I suppose to get `lenovo` (id:1) and `lg` (id:2) but i only get `lg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-wherein) to be able to pass an array of values:

```
$brandspromotion = Brand::OfStatus('Active')->whereIn('id', $grouped)->get();
```

Comment: Result is the same, still i only get `1` brand returned.

Comment: Ok, I changed my query to my `update 2` and with your suggestion now is getting what i exactly need. Thank you.